# User validation using Jquery & PHP

Tags: php, jquery

User validation using Jquery & PHP is failing
Even if a valid user id is entered I get a response back saying the user does not exist
user.php

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {     
 $('#check_username_availability').click(function()
 {
 check_availability();
 });

 function check_availability(){ 
 var username = $('#username').val(); 
  $.post("checkdata.php", {username:username},  
        function(result){  
            //if the result is 1  
            if(result == '1'){  
                //show that the username is available  
                $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is  Available');  
            }else{  
                //show that the username is NOT available  
                $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is not Available');  
            }
    });    

    }
    });  </script>

<input type='text' id='username' name = 'username' > 
<input type='button' id='check_username_availability' value='Check    
 Avaliability'>  
<div id='username_availability_result'></div>
```

Checkdata php - This is the php code which does the validation

```
<?php
$user = "root";
$pwd = "admin";
$host = "localhost";
$db = "MProject";
$link=@mysql_connect($host,$user,$pwd) or die( "Could not connect to MySQL");
$db_link = mysql_select_db($db) or die( "Could not connect to user db");
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE uid = '$username'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($numrows > 0)
{
     echo "1";
}
    else
{
    echo "0";
}
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: What does the PHP return? You shouldn't use error suppression and should update to `pdo` or `mysqli`.

Comment: your logic is backwards, you return 1 for the username being in the db, then say in the js 1=Available

Comment: all the usual mysql_* is bad should be noted as well

Comment: I have also tried replacing echo with return, it doesn't work.

Comment: I have verified the checkdata.php by displaying the results as a separate webpage. It works as expected.There is some issue while i try to pass the data from user.php, which i am unable to figure out.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I have managed to fix it. In my checkdata.php i was using the <html> tags, which was also being returned. After i removed the tags it started working as expected.